# page is not scrolling vertically in mobile devices

Tags: html, css, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I'm working on a project. There is an issue on the front end side. The site is responsive, but when I view it in mobile width *(specially for iPhone 4 & 5)*, the vertical scroll doesn't work.

I'm not using any div that needs scrolling, the  whole page is not scrolling vertically, I'm afraid I can't provide the code. The thing I wanna know is why does this happens? and what would I've possibly done wrong?

1) I have added `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` on body tag but my chrome browser is not picking it up and saying invalid property.

2) I have added `body{overflow-y:scroll,position:relative}` Now its showing a scroll but there is no bar between the scroll, and its pretty much stuck there.

Comment: Do you maybe have `overflow: hidden;` on `body` or `html`?

Comment: no there is no overflow hidden.

Comment: Maybe its some plugin. Can you post link to your website? I remember i had same issue once.

Comment: @NenadVracar, im sorry i checked it again and there was actually an overflow:hidden at max-width:320px media query, i commented it, but the scroll is still not working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think its because of `position` and `z-index` the `z-index` value make problem in your small screen.

Its possible that the element which have high `z-index` value. stopping you for scroll.

and It can be possible you have `overflow:hidden` in wrong place. It will be good, If you show some code of line or your site link.

Comment: Yeah there was overflow:hidden in html tag, i've set it to overflow:scroll and its working perfectly fine.